# $H^s \subset C_0$ and infinity norm of a tempered distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading chapter 11 of [Applied Analysis by John Hunter and Bruno Nachtergaele](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/book/ch11.pdf). On definition 11.38 (page 313) they define the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R^n})$ as the space of all **distributions** $f\in S^*$ whose Fourier transform $\hat{f}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is a regular distribution and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|k|^2)^s|\hat{f}(k)|^2dk<\infty.
$$
Exercise 11.12 (page 330) claims that if $s>n/2$, then $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and that there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
||f||_\infty\leq C||f||_{H^s} \text{     for all } f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n).
$$

**Question 1:** How should the inclusion $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be interpreted? For regular distributions it makes sense, but what about singular distributions?

**Question 2:** In the inequality, what exactly is $||f||_\infty$ when $f$ is a distribution? Again for regular distributions it makes sense but for singular distributions I don't know the definition, and it is not in the notes either.